# How to customize the default .Net Framework Validation Error Messages

Tags: c#, .net

I have in my view model the following code:

```
public DateTime? Activation_Date { get; set; }
public DateTime? Deactivation_Date { get; set; }
```

On the form, if I put the date as "abc" and click Save, I get the following validation error:

```
The value 'abc' is not valid for Activation_Date.
```

What I simply want is to modify Activation_Date. I want it to be "Activation Date" so the message will look like below. The end user doesn't want the underscore.

```
The value 'abc' is not valid for Activation Date.
```

View Code to display error messages

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.Activation_Date)
```

What is the technique to make this kind of change ?

Comment: What validation are you talking about? Which stack and which validation library? Are you using data annotations? Some validation attributes allow you to set the error message you want. The error itself may be affected by the `Display` attribute in which case you can specify a different name or prompt. You can create your own errors for different stacks.

Comment: I display the message as follows:  `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.Activation_Date)`